# EntityManager from LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean does not persist entities into the database

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, apache-camel

The problem is that the `EntityManager` injected with `@PersistenceContext` in a Spring managed bean does not persist the entities to the database. I have tried using `@Transactional` on the `AddDao` bean, where `entityManager.persist()` is called (I have enabled annotation-driven transactions).

The transaction begins in another bean which is instantiated by Camel with `.transacted()` in the Camel Java DSL. That bean has an `@Autowired` property which is the DAO and has the `EntityManager` injected with `@PersistenceContext`.

As transaction manager Bitronix is used.

A portion of the Spring xml configuration file looks like this:

```
  <bean id="localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="btmConfig" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="nameFromPersistenceXml"/>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="package with @Entity POJOs"/>

  </bean>



  <bean id="btmConfig" factory-method="getConfiguration"
      class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices">
    <property name="serverId" value="spring-btm" />
  </bean>

  <!-- create BTM transaction manager -->
  <bean id="BitronixTransactionManager" factory-method="getTransactionManager"
      class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices" depends-on="btmConfig"
      destroy-method="shutdown" />
  <!-- Spring JtaTransactionManager -->
  <bean id="springTransactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="BitronixTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="BitronixTransactionManager" />
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="springTransactionManager" />
```

Edit: In a overly simplified version it looks like this:

In Camel Java DSL there is

```
from("wsLayer")
   .transacted()
   .otherProcessing()
   .to("bean:addBean?method=addMyEntity")
```

And add beans look something like this:

```
@Component
public class AddBean {
    @Autowired
    private AddDao addDao;

    public void addMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity) {
        //other business logic
        addDao.persistMyEntity(myEntity);
    }
}

@Component
public class AddDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    //I have tried here 
    //@Transactional and 
    //@Transactional(propagation = PropagationType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void persistMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity) {
        entityManager.persist(myEntity);
    }
}
```

The reading from the database works well.

See the data source:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="uniqueName" value="theName" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" ><value>${db.pool.maxSize}</value></property>
    <property name="minPoolSize" ><value>${db.pool.minSize}</value></property>    
    <property name="allowLocalTransactions" ><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="automaticEnlistingEnabled" ><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="className" ><value>${db.pool.datasource}</value></property>
    <property name="driverProperties" ref="databaseProperties" />
</bean>
```

where the properties are set in Maven's `pom.xml` like this:

```
 db.pool.maxSize=15
 db.pool.maxSize=5
 db.pool.datasource=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
```

Comment: You didn't put the code of the entity you're trying to persist in your post, could it be a "large object" case?
Check this [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/largeobjects.html). Hope it helps. Edit: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362531/how-do-you-auto-commit-an-sql-server-transaction-in-jpa).

Comment: Actually it doesn't persist none of the domain objects, neither the large nor the small ones. It persists them to the cache/entityManager but not to the database (which is PostgreSQL btw); after calling `em.persist(entity)` and immediately after `em.contains(entity)` the result is true but the `entity` isn't actually persisted to the database. I'm guessing is has something to do with transactions. Regarding the links, the objects are mapped normally and the transactions are `JTA` in `persistence.xml` and not `RESOURCE_LOCAL` as discussed there.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to execute em.flush() after em.persist(entity)?
According with the docs of Java EE:

em.persist(entity): Make an instance managed and persistent.
BUT
em.flush(entity): Synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database.

So, you can do something like:

```
em.persist(myEntity);
em.flush();
```

And check if this change make a difference.

Comment: I have tried that, and this doesn't make any difference; what I haven't tried is `em.merge(entity)`, I'll try that.

Comment: It also doesn't work with `em.merge(entity)` with or without `em.flush()` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

From the limited symptoms given, seems like the JTA transaction is not being started and propagated.  Your EM would work fine up to a point - reading from DB, allowing data changes against it's Persistent Context cache, but never writing to the DB.

Think it's a config problem and your @Transaction annotations are being ignored.

> *I have enabled annotation-driven transactions.*

Make sure it's configured as follows in your Spring configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="springTransactionManager"/>
```

where:

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
```

Comment: That's exactly how it the problem. The transaction should have been created by Camel. Besides the namespace there is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd` in `xsi:schemaLocation`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the @Transactional in this way

```
@Component
public class AddDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional("BitronixTransactionManager")
    public void persistMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity) {
        entityManager.persist(myEntity);
    }
}
```